# Bootstrap - Grid Layout of List Items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page in which I'm using Bootstrap 3. In this page, I want to have a list of 4 panels place together in a 2x2 grid. I want the grid to basically looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
|  3  |  4  |
|  C  |  D  |
+-----+-----+
```

I want the grid to be styled like the a [list-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group) though. By styled, I mean have border stylings and internal padding like a list-group item. I do not want a single column of items. While I've been able to get close as shown in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CCYIE9jfWm), it's not quite there. There is still a blank line between the first and second rows in the grid. But, if I get rid of the blank line, the borders between the rows don't look correct. In addition, I'm not sure if I should use the `width:50%` like I'm using.

My code in question looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal block" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="width:50%;">
      <h4>Portion 1</h4>
      <h4><small>This is a description</small></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="width:50%;">
      <h4>Portion 2</h4>
      <h4><small>This is a description</small></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal block" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="width:50%;">
      <h4>Portion 3</h4>
      <h4><small>This is a description</small></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="list-group-item" style="width:50%;">
      <h4>Portion 4</h4>
      <h4><small>This is a description</small></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing incorrect in my approach to this layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular list-group. Then use css to remove the unwanted rounded corners and to position 2 list-groups next to each other

see below snippet or bootply: http://www.bootply.com/iYq8A9nVZQ

```css
.my-list-group {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
  
.left .list-group-item {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
    
.right .list-group-item {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group my-list-group left">
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <h1>item 1</h1>
      <p>sub</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <h1>item 3</h1>
      <p>sub</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group my-list-group right">
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <h1>item 2</h1>
      <p>sub</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <h1>item 4</h1>
      <p>sub</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason the snippet does not seem to fix the rounded corners, check the bootply for the correct visual result

Answer (score 0):

You have to override default margin-bottom of *.list-group* to remove the blank line:

```
.list-group-horizontal {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Then you can remove top border of items in second row:

```
.list-group-horizontal + .list-group-horizontal > .list-group-item {
    border-top: 0;
}
```